# FromBody is null

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am doing a post to an api and for whatever reason i keep getting a null value I am using Angular2 to call the api service, in the [FromBody] and not sure why. I have the following

component

```
fileInfo: IFile;//this is an interface
this.fileInfo = {
    FileID:1000,
    LinkTabID: 1,
    FileName: 'Test',
    FileDisplayName: 'test',
    IsActive: true,
    CreatedBy: 'mike',
    UpdatedBy:'mike'
}

this._tabService.AddFile(this.fileInfo)
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.tabControls = data;
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

Service

```
AddFile(fileInfo: IFile){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.post(this._fileUploadAPI + 'InsertFile' , { fileInfo }, options)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

in my fiddler i see the raw data
[image]

WebAPI

```
public HttpResponseMessage InsertFile([FromBody] FileModel value)
{
    try
    {
      //  sp_GetFileResult fileEntry = _modelFactory.Parse(value);

        if (fileEntry == null)
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could not read file entry in the body");
        else
        {
            some logic
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
    }
}
```

***********ALSO TRIED****************************************

```
AddFile(fileInfo: IFile){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.post(this._fileUploadAPI + 'InsertFile', { value: fileInfo }, options)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

jason
[image]

got the same error

FileModel

```
public class FileModel
    {

     public int FileID { get; set; }
     public int  LinkTabID { get; set; }
     public string  FileName { get; set; }
     public string FileDisplayName { get; set; }
     public bool  IsActive { get; set; }
     public  string CreatedBy { get; set; }
     public  string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: what is the structure of FileModel?

Comment: I suspect that the nested inner objects of "value" and "fileInfo" highlight that it is just a single interface, try removing those inner objects and just posting the properties directly.

Comment: removed the inner objects and still got the, same result

Comment: added my filemodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it , just needed to add "result" to my jason

```
AddFile(fileInfo: IFile){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.post(this._fileUploadAPI + 'InsertFile', { result: fileInfo }, options)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

instead of

```
AddFile(fileInfo: IFile){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.post(this._fileUploadAPI + 'InsertFile', { value: fileInfo }, options)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```